# CodenameOne: MultiList component is missing setScrollableY method

Tags: codenameone

I created a MultiList inside a Scrollable Form. I would like to disable the MultiList' scrolling but the MultiList lacks the setScrollableY() method.

Is there a way to accomplish disabling scrolling on the MultiList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not missing it's intentional. You could override isScrollableY() to return false but that's the wrong approach to disable scrolling. Lists have a lot of inherent expectations so you probably shouldn't do that as it will impact layout/rendering etc.

I would generally suggest [avoiding lists](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/avoiding-lists.html).